# A post office only sells stamps worth 3c and 2c. Show that any postage of value greater than 2c can be paid for using only these two stamps.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Not sure how to proceed with this. If someone could help answer or start it off, I'd appreciate it

Comment: Divide into cases according to whether you need to reach an even or an odd number of cents.

Comment: If the postage has an even price, we can simply buy a multiple of $2$-cent stamps. What if the postage has an odd price?

Comment: To make the problem simpler,show that you need at most one 3c stamp

Comment: @Harry by multiplying by 2 then adding 1?

Comment: @NihalMandava Instead you could buy one $3$-cent stamp, and the remaining price would be even. Then we know what to do. I would suggest looking at Jaideep's answer for a more rigorous explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Each natural number $n>2$ can be written as $3k,3k+1$ or $3k+2$ (where $k\in \mathbb N)$. The following cases arise -

$\color{blue}{n=3k}$, you need $k$ stamps worth 3c.

$\color{blue}{n=3k+1}=3(k-1)+4$, you need $k-1$ stamps worth 3c and two stamps worth 2c.

$\color{blue}{n=3k+2}$, you need $k$ stamps worth 3c and one stamp worth 2c.

Hence, any postage of value greater than $2$ can be paid by at least on way, using 3c and 2c stamps.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks for explaining thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

If $n =$ amount is even, use all $2c$ stamps.
If odd eg. $n+1$, use ($n/2-1$) '$2c$' stamps and one '$3c$' stamp

Answer (score 0):

This is true because for any odd number $n>2$, you can write it as $2\color{blue}k + 1$, and as such, you can write it as $\color{blue}{(k-1)}2 + \color{red}1(3)$, where $k-1$ are $\color{blue}{\mathbb{two~cents}}$ and $1$ of $\color{red}{\mathbb{three~cents}}$.

And for even numbers, just take $n/2$ of two cents pennies.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that if the value is an $even$ number then we can just use $\frac{value}{2}$ number of $2c$ stamps.

If the value is an $odd$ number then we just use one $3c$ stamp and $\frac{value - 1}{2} - 1$ number of $2c$ stamps.

This way we can get all the $even$ values when $value$ is $even$. And by adding one $3c$ stamp in the beginning instead of a $2c$ stamp, when $value$ is $odd$, we essentially do the same as we did when $value$ was $even$, but we add $1$. Therefore we can cover all of the $odd$ and $even$ numbers over and including $2$.